# com+ does not work if windows server does not login

Tags: com+

My problem is how to make com+ active when windows server does not login?
(This situation is I select "Interactive user" option on the Set Application Identity page of the Component Services)

On the Set Application Identity page of the Component Services, I had already tried the following options:

1. select (This user) "administrator".
2. select LocalService
3. select NetworkService
   It did NOT work......

I had already run (regsvr32) to un-register & re-register the my DLL using administrator privilege.
It did NOT work, TOO......

Would somebody HELP, PLEASE...

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a user account in computer management.
2. Add newly created user account to "Distributed COM Users" group.
3. Go to COM+ application that you are configuring and then change "Identity" to the user you created in step 1.

Following above steps should make COM+ component active as soon as it gets request even if user is not logged in to machine. I hope this helps.